# when you pass on the link of the quiz, the application must open the desired category and open the popup how to do it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

There is a list of quizzes, quiz opens in the popup menu. The user can start passing the quiz and at the end of may to share a link to a quiz in social networks. A user can share a link to a quiz such as Twitter. If he clicks on the link, it should open a popup with a quiz.

when you pass on the link of the quiz, the application must open the desired category and open the popup how to do it?

click on link and open popup with quiz:

```
link_to('play', quiz_path(quiz), class: "play-button", remote: true)
```

in show.js

```
QuizPopup.initPopup("content");
QuizPopup.renderPopup();
```

JS

```
renderPopup: function(){
  React.render(
    React.createElement(
         MDQuiz, 
         $('#modalContent>:first').data('react-props')),
         document.getElementById("modalContent").children[0]);
},
initPopup: function(content){
  $('#modal').dialog({
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    autoOpen: true,
    hide: 'drop',
  });
  $('#modalContent').html(content);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `link_to('play', quiz_path(quiz), class: "play-button", remote: true)` doing ?

Comment: wait, sorry I missed the ruby-on-rails tag